# Looping through a two dimensional array of values in java and print only the 2nd element of the array

Tags: java, html

I have all the states and its abbreviation in a two-dimensional array, see below

```
String[][] stateList = {

        {"AL","Alabama"},
        {"AK","Alaska"},
        {"AB","Alberta"},       
        {"AS","American Somoa"},
        {"AZ","Arizona"},
        {"AR","Arkansas"},
        {"BC","British Columbia"},
        .....
        .....
}
```

I want to loop through this array and print only the full state name.

This is for an input field with options for states selection, upon selection, the respective abbreviation (AS, AZ, AR, AK) goes to the server.

If the page has an erroneous or a missing value, the page throws error normally upon submission, but I noticed that the state select option now has the abbreviation and not the full state name, which wouldn't allow the page to be submitted.

I want the state select option to have only stateList{"","Alabama"} and not AL

I tried doing it in Javascript but I want it in Java

```
var state = (#stateselection).val();

for(i=0; i<stateList[][].length; i++)
{
   if (stateList[i][0] === "AL")
   {
     state = stateList[i][1];
   }
}
```

This is the HTML portion with a bit of tag libs

```
<div id="usstates" class="usstates_all">

<label for="SELECTEDSTATE">STATE:</label> <br>

<select name="allstates" class="form-cntrl" id="usstates" onchange="setStates(this);">

<option disabled="" selected="" value="">Select a State</option>

<D:if test="${not empty vs['SELECTEDSTATE'] }">
<option selected value="${vs['SELECTEDSTATE']}">${vs['SELECTEDSTATE']}</option>
</D:if>


<option value="AL">Alabama</option>
<option value="AK">Alaska</option>
<option value="AS">American Samoa</option>
<option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
<option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
<option value="CA">California</option>
<option value="CO">Colorado</option>
<option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
<option value="DE">Delaware</option>
<option value="DC">District of Columbia</option>
..............
..............
```

when I fill the form "State: Alabama", after submit, if some error occurs, I fix it and then hit submit, "It says select your state" when I saw the state field, it was "AL" and not Alabama.

Comment: You should provide your current java code that constructs the html to give further guidance

Comment: @deechris27 Check my solution , Upvote or approve if it's helpful

Comment: I've added the html part as well now, let me know..

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
String[][] stateList = new String[][]{
                         {"AL","Alabama"},
                         {"AK","Alaska"},
                         {"AB","Alberta"},        
                         {"BC","British Columbia"}
                       };

for (String[] state : stateList) {
      System.out.print("\n"+state[0]); // Print First element
      System.out.print(" -"+state[1]); // Print Second element

}
```

---

```
Output:     
AL -Alabama
AK -Alaska
AB -Alberta
BC -British Columbia
```

Comment: I think that the OP asked for a way to construct an input (a select input I presume) in html in a way that it shows a list with the abbreviations but sends the full name to the server when submitting the form

Answer (score 0):

```
String[][] states =   {
    {"AL","Alabama"},
    {"AK","Alaska"},
    {"AB","Alberta"},       
    {"AS","American Somoa"},
    {"AZ","Arizona"},
    {"AR","Arkansas"},
    {"BC","British Columbia"}};

    for(int i=0;i<7;i++){
    System.out.println(states[i][1]); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Try the following:`

```
String[][] stateList = {
    {"AL","Alabama"},
    {"AK","Alaska"},
    {"AB","Alberta"},       
    {"AS","American Somoa"},
    {"AZ","Arizona"},
    {"AR","Arkansas"},
    {"BC","British Columbia"}
}
String alState;
for (String[] state: stateList) {
    if (state[0].equals("AL"))
    {
        alState = state[1];
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow and thanks for your answer. A little explanation will improve the quality and acceptability of your answer.

Comment: This  is your js script in java